# Is it ok to edit 3rd party javascript plugins?

Tags: javascript, plugins, open-source

We need to edit the source code (a single javascript file) of a 3rd party plugin to make its UI rendered with bootstrap classes. This plugin does not download as a node module (npm). So is it okay to do that ? Because i have heard some people say - never edit source code of 3rd party plugins. Thanks.

Comment: You can do whatever you like, but it's not recommended to edit a 3rd party library. This is because they tend to change a lot, and you'll not be able to "upgrade".

Comment: Check their licences and how your work is going to be presented.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Actually this is not a 3rd party library, but jQuery text editor, and fullcalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - check the license of the plugin.

Second - the reason why it is not recommended to change a plugin is that if you are upgrading the script - your edit will be lost, and it hard to track such problems. It is better to make the code maintainers change their code, with offering them the change, create new git branch in their repository etc.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it, but you risk breaking other parts in the library itself that you may not be aware of. It's possible that your changes could have side effects and puts you at a disadvantage when it comes time to upgrade the library. But in the end you should follow the license to see what you're allowed to do.

If it's a change that could be beneficial to others, then contribute to the project with your changes.

You could also try overriding the specific part you need in a separate file.